# Eloquent ORM not save value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

I want to update my data using Eloquent but it gave me some error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'od_logo.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `od_logo` where `od_logo`.`id` = 1 limit 1)
```

Here is my code:

```
$logo = Logo::find($id);
$logo->logo_logoimg_name       = Input::get('logo_name');
$logo->logo_logoimg_path      = $logo_destinationPath . $logo_filename;
$logo->logo_faviconimg_name = $favicon_destinationPath . $favicon_filename;
$logo->save();
```

Please find where I do wrong in this code

Comment: Is your primary key column called `id` or something else?

Comment: My primary key called logo_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your primary key column is not called `id` (which is the default Laravel assumes) you have to specify it in your model:

```
class Logo extends Eloquent {
    protected $primaryKey = 'logo_id';
}
```

Quote from the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage):

> Note: Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named id. You may define a primaryKey property to override this convention.